# Can you put on tefillin after shekia on Friday

Tags: halacha, tefilin

May one put on tefillin after Shekia on Friday, or does he just miss the boat?

Comment: Why Friday? [15]

Comment: Shabbat, unless I miss the mark

Comment: This question would be much more valuable and answerable if you'ed [edit] in why a person would want to put on tefillin then (i.e. what boat would he be missing otherwise), why you think this may be permitted, and why you think it may be forbidden. The more of what you already understand that you put into the question, the more likely you'll get answers that address whatever you're missing.

Comment: I had once that i forgot to put רבינו ת"ם תפילין on a Friday till after candle lighting, so I'm wondering if it would be a problem to put tefillin then...

Comment: @ElyeM. Well for RT it wouldn't be Shabbat yet...